# How to reduce memory while we Zip a big excel file in java

Tags: excel, file, zip

I am trying to zip a 30Mb excel file. 
Wrapping th fileinputstream and fileoutputstream reduced some of the memory consumption.
Please suggest if you have a better option than this approach.
Do you think, flushing the ZipOutputStream after zos.write() inside while loop will be of any advantage?
Following is the code which i use.

```
public void zipBigFile()
        throws IOException, ParseException {

    String outFileName= "D:/Out/Big.zip";

    File file = new File(outFileName);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(out));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 8];

        String inFileName = "D:/In/Big_File.xlsx";
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inFileName);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("Big_File_Zipped.xlsx");
        zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);


        int length;
        while ((length = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        zos.closeEntry();
        fis.close();
        fis = null;

    buffer = null;

    zos.flush();
    zos.close();
    out.close();
    out = null;
    zos = null;

}
```

Comment: what makes you think this is eating too much memory?  What is memory utilization when you run this?

Comment: This is not taking too much memory. Still, I am trying to achieve the best memory utilization. What i really want to know is, will putting zos.flush() inside while loop can still reduce the memory usage?

Comment: you are wasting your time solving a problem you do not have.

Comment: :D thats rgt. But i got some spare time to work on. So thought of going for an optimization. can you tell me the difference between fush() & write() of ZipOutputStream, which i am not able to understand properly from java doc?